# Risks of creating a user with no shell

Tags: authentication, linux

Are there any security risks when creating a user(s) with no shell, and no special privileges (using fairly strong passwords)?

### Reasons

- To redirect the attackers attention from "real" users (e.g. real user "smr", fake user "admin")
- Secure logging of attempts to break into the system
- Better distinguishable from login attempts to real accounts

*Additional:* How to notify an admin of "too many" suspicious attempts / what best to do?

Comment: Could you please explain more about the question? I don't understand how someone can break into your system if they can't get a shell in the first place? It's like trying to break into www-data via SSH, no one does it.

Comment: @99Con looking for unauthorised attempted access. www-data tries to log into ssh all the time, when using automated scanners ...

Comment: Oh, I understand, if you're looking for attempted access then why don't you just look at the SSH logs for your server? You should look at https://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page, this has what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like a level of *obscurity*. In order to protect your admin account, the recommended way is to have a strong password, or even better an asymetric key on SSH. You can **in addition** provide a *honey pot* login named `admin`, but it does not add a lot of security, nor avoid logs examinations for real logins. IMHO, it would be mainly interesting if you were studying the behaviour of attackers, because no *normal* login attemps should occur on the honeypot.

As usually for obscurity, nothing is wrong if you do not rely on it but only see it as an additional protection level.